# Angular routing doesn't open the desired default url

Tags: angular, typescript, web, routes

I'm building a site in Angular 10 but I'm getting some confusion around routing.
The app routing is configured as follows:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const accountModule = () => import('./account/account.module').then(x => x.AccountModule);
const onboardingModule = () => import('./onboarding/onboarding.module').then(x => x.OnboardingModule);
const memberDashboardModule = () => import('./member-dashboard/member-dashboard.module').then(x => x.MemberDashboardModule);
const adminDashboardModule = () => import('./admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.module').then(x => x.AdminDashboardModule);

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'account', loadChildren: accountModule },
  { path: 'onboarding', loadChildren: onboardingModule },
  { path: 'member-dashboard', loadChildren: memberDashboardModule },
  { path: 'admin-dashboard', loadChildren: adminDashboardModule },
  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'member-dashboard', pathMatch: "full" }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And the member dashboard module's routing is the following:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';
import { UpdateProfileComponent } from './update-profile/update-profile.component'
import { ViewTeamsComponent } from './view-teams/view-teams.component'
import { CreateTeamComponent } from './create-team/create-team.component';
import { UpdateTeamComponent } from './update-team/update-team.component';
import { ViewNotificationsComponent } from './view-notifications/view-notifications.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [           
            { path: 'profile', component: UpdateProfileComponent },
            { path: 'notifications', component: ViewNotificationsComponent },
            { path: 'teams', component: ViewTeamsComponent },
            { path: 'teams/create-team', component: CreateTeamComponent },
            { path: 'teams/update-team', component: UpdateTeamComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MemberDashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Where layout is just handling the children display within a the common visual/styled frame (header, sidebar, etc.)

```html
<div class="full-screen-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I would like users browsing the root (e.g. http://localhost:8081) or anything that is not /member-dashboard, /admin-dashboard, /account or /onboarding, such as (http://localhost:8081/notExpectedPath) to be redirected to http://localhost:8081/member-dashboard/profile.
Though, when I type http://localhost:8081 I get redirected to http://localhost:8081/profile.

Can you help me figuring it out?

Comment: This has nothing to do with lazy loaded modules. You need a "catch-all" / "wildcard" / "**" route. See here: https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#define-a-wildcard-route for an how-to.

Comment: I updated the title of the question to better reflect the problem. I hope I interpreted your problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you don't have a rule matching "whatever", and so the router is going through all the rules you setup, is finding nothing matches, and is activating the last one.

You need a "catch-all" route. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#define-a-wildcard-route) for a description.

To implement your requirement you need to add just one extra route as the absolute last in the array:

```js
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/member-dashboard' }
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I keep the empty path rule in app routing or just replace it with the wildcard? Anyway I gotta say this tutorial https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules that I followed is a bit confusing, cause it doesn’t use wildcard path and states “The first two paths are the routes to the CustomersModule and the OrdersModule. The final entry defines a default route. The empty path matches everything that doesn't match an earlier path.”, where “the final entry” is indeed the empty path rule.

Comment: The guide is correct, but you mixed and matched two different guides: you are using `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'full' }` without understanding the `pathMatch: 'full'` bit. The routes are matched (by default) as _part_ of the inserted url. So the route 'something' will match also 'something/else'. Except if you use `pathMatch: 'full'`. An empty url without pathmatch will act exactly like a catch-all (but I find it confusing, so I always use '**'). The two can have different uses: the empty url can be used as the default route, while the ** is for a classic "Not Found" page.

Comment: And, if the answer is accepted, you should mark it as the accepted answer (and upvote it if it's of value).

Comment: If I use wildcard in both app routing and member dashboard routing:

// member-dashboard.routing.ts
    {
        path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [           
            { path: 'profile', component: UpdateProfileComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: "full" }, 
        ]
    }

// app-routing.ts
  { path: 'member-dashboard', loadChildren: memberDashboardModule },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/member-dashboard' }

It still doesn't work: mywebsite.com is redirected to mywebsite.com/profile/member-dashboard/profile.

Comment: It looks like { path: '**', redirectTo: '/member-dashboard' } will keep processing the routes defined in member-dashboard module and match them against the remaining url segments (which is "") without appending "member-dashboard" to the activated url.